# adding missing value to multi-index data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe that groups values across two column.
The dataframe changes over time and, for each period, I add the grouped results to a new dataframe that looks like:

| Name | Win/Loose | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Soccer | Win | 5 | 6 |
|  | Loose | 7 | 5 |
| baseball | Win | 2 | 3 |
|  | Loose | 5 | 4 |
| basketball | Win | 9 | 7 |
|  | loose | 4 | 6 |

```
old_results = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Soccer','Soccer','baseball','baseball', 'basketball', 'basketball'],
                            'Win/Loose':['win','Loose','win','Loose','win','Loose'], 
                            '2022':[5,7,2,5,9,4],
                            '2023':[6,5,3,4,7,6]}).set_index(['name', 'Win/Loose'])
```

The problem is that I can't concatenate new periods with the existing dataframe when it doesn't have a matching index. In this case it is a multi-indec of 'Name' and 'Win/Loose'. For some periods, as in the above example, I only have Wins and no losses.

But if I try to concatenate a new period, say 2024 with the following results:

| Name | Win/Loose | 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Soccer | Win | 8 |
|  | Loose | 4 |
| baseball | Win | 6 |
|  | Loose | 1 |
| basketball | Win | 13 |

```
new_results = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Soccer','Soccer','baseball','baseball', 'basketball'],
                            'Win/Loose':['win','Loose','win','Loose','win'], 
                            '2024':[8,4,6,1,13]}).set_index(['name', 'Win/Loose'])
```

It fails becuase there is no "Loose" row in the new table.

I am using the following code to concatenate the two data frames:

```
updated_results = pd.concat([old_results, new_results], axis=1, join="inner")
```

Which results in the following error:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

I am expecting the new updated results dataframe to be a merge of old_results and new_results.

I think I need to loop throught the new data frame to make sure I have zero values, where there are no wins or losses in a group but I am lsot on how to go about that.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does it "fail"? Is there an error message? Is the result unexpected?

Comment: updated with error message and expected result

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
update_results = old_results.join(new_results)
```

As long as old_results is the superset of new_result.